# Diameter receiving response from different Host for request

Tags: diameter-protocol

Diameter: Let us consider one server sent one diameter request to the host1.com(for eg: AA over Rx) Can i receive a response from another host say host2.com. Is this a valid scenario ?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can see this happening a lot in the diameter world.

You have request with dest-host: X and receives response from Orig-Host: Y.

It happens sometimes because there is a pool of servers, sometimes because other peer “stole” the request and there are probably more reasons.

But I started with Unfortunately because sometime diameter peers take this Y and use it in the next request as dest-host AVP (instead of using X as they should)

**This is why it is not recommended to do so**